# Get the real type of a protocol to compare with type stored in a variable

Tags: swift

I would like to be able to check the object's type of an object that implements a certain protocol.

In the following method, I would like to be able to loop over all the objects from my array of `IObject` objects and find the one that has as its real type, the type passed in parameter.

```
func findObject(forType type: Any) -> IObject? {
  for (key, value) in self.objects {
    if value.Type == type {
      return value
    }
  }

  return nil
}
```

When I try to compile the above code, I've an error message saying: `'IObject' does not have a member named 'Type'`.

Any suggestion?

Comment: What type has `self.objects` and how do you want to call this method? `findObject(forType: IObjectSubclass.self)` or `findObject(forType: IObjectSubclass())` and check the type of the object against the one in the dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Swift 2 with Xcode 7 beta 6.

I found this question interesting. The only way I have managed to get this to work is by string comparison - i.e. `if "\(object.dynamicType)" == "\(forType)"`.

Also - if I have properly understood the question then I think that the function possibly needs to return an optional array of `IObject` - because the array of objects may contain more than one of the given type.

```
protocol IObject: class {}
class SomeObject1: IObject {}
class SomeObject2: IObject {}

let myIObject01 = SomeObject1()
let myIObject02 = SomeObject2()
let myIObject03 = SomeObject1()
let myIObject04 = SomeObject1()
let myIObject05 = SomeObject2()

var objects: [IObject] = [myIObject01,myIObject02,myIObject03,myIObject04,myIObject05]

func findObject(forType: Any) -> [IObject]? {
    var result = [IObject]()
    for object in objects {
        if "\(object.dynamicType)" == "\(forType)" {
            result.append(object)
        }
    }
    return result
}

let result = findObject(SomeObject1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this code:

```
if value.Type == type
```

to this:

```
if value.dynamicType == type
```

If it still doesn't work, try this:

```
if value.dynamicType == type.self
```